# Bigcommerce Python API, how do I create a product with an image?

Tags: python, e-commerce, bigcommerce

how do I upload an image (from the web) using Bigcommerce's Python API?

I've got this so far:

`custom = api.Products.create(name='Test', type='physical', price=8.33, categories=[85], availability='available', weight=0)`

Thank you! I've tried almost everything!

Comment: Maybe check out [this page](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#create-a-product-image). I think you would create an product image object, and then add it to your product above as the `primary_image`

Answer (score -2):

This will create the product on the BigCommerce website. You create the image after creating the product, by entering the following line. The `image_file` tag should be a fully qualified URL pointing to an image that is accessible to the BigCommerce website, being found either on another website or on your own webserver.

`api.ProductImages.create(parentid=custom.id, image_file='http://www.evenmore.co.uk/images/emgrab_s.jpg', description='My image description')`