# Attach an image file to a BigCommerce Product

Tags: multipartform-data, bigcommerce

The [BigCommerce API documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/catalog.html#createproductimage) suggests that image files can be uploaded through the API, without having to upload it elsewhere first:

> `POST /catalog/products/{product_id}/images`
>
> Creates an image on a product. Publically accessible URLs and **files (form post)** are valid parameters

Emphasis mine. My attempts, variations on the below, mostly come back with `422 image_url must be present if uploading by url`.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/redacted/v3/catalog/products/123/images \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'x-auth-client: redacted' \
  -H 'x-auth-token: redacted' \
  -F productImage=@img_123.jpg \
  -F image_url=image_123.jpg
```

What does a correctly formed request look like, that `POST`s an image file to a product?

---

## Related:

- [Bigcommerce Python API, how do I create a product with an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42003461/2014893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correctly formed request looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/js......7j/v3/catalog/products/32011/images \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'  \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'x-auth-client: ts2.........................r0r' \
  -H 'x-auth-token: ihq.........................5b2' \
  -F 'image_file=@Downloads/img_2405.jpg'
```

However, certain images can cause the misleading error; such as [this one.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0AT8WPGB9BldzJTYnB1WXpSOHM/view)

It's not clear what property of the file causes the error, but compressing or otherwise re-saving the image resolves the problem.